# vscode python comment togglging does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to vscode.

I have used shortcut (commad + /) for toggling comments. But nowadays, this does not work for python codes. (This still work for my java codes) I guess some problems exist with python extensions but not sure. Can anybody help me?

Below is my environment.

### System information

```
CPUs | Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz (4 x 2700)
-- | --
GPU Status | 2d_canvas: enabledflash_3d: enabledflash_stage3d: enabledflash_stage3d_baseline: enabledgpu_compositing: enabledmetal: disabled_offmultiple_raster_threads: enabled_onoop_rasterization: disabled_offprotected_video_decode: unavailable_offrasterization: enabledskia_renderer: disabled_off_okvideo_decode: enabledviz_display_compositor: enabled_onviz_hit_test_surface_layer: disabled_off_okwebgl: enabledwebgl2: enabled
Load (avg) | 3, 3, 3
Memory (System) | 8.00GB (0.38GB free)
Process Argv | .
Screen Reader | no
VM | 0%
```

### Extensions installed

```
Extension | Author (truncated) | Version
-- | -- | --
vscode-django | bat | 0.20.0
npm-intellisense | chr | 1.3.0
path-intellisense | chr | 2.2.1
bracket-pair-colorizer | Coe | 1.0.61
vscode-markdownlint | Dav | 0.36.3
vscode-eslint | dba | 2.1.8
githistory | don | 0.6.9
python-extension-pack | don | 1.6.0
LogFileHighlighter | emi | 2.9.0
json-tools | eri | 1.0.2
prettier-vscode | esb | 5.5.0
code-runner | for | 0.11.0
mdmath | goe | 2.5.1
gc-excelviewer | Gra | 3.0.40
vscode-auto-open-markdown-preview | hnw | 0.0.4
vsc-python-indent | Kev | 1.11.0
node-module-intellisense | lei | 1.5.0
sftp | lix | 1.12.9
MagicPython | mag | 1.1.0
rainbow-csv | mec | 1.7.1
dotenv | mik | 1.0.1
prettify-json | moh | 0.0.3
vscode-language-pack-ko | MS- | 1.48.3
python | ms- | 2020.8.106424
remote-containers | ms- | 0.134.1
remote-ssh | ms- | 0.51.0
remote-ssh-edit | ms- | 0.51.0
remote-wsl | ms- | 0.44.5
vscode-remote-extensionpack | ms- | 0.20.0
color-highlight | nau | 2.3.0
vscode-jsp | pth | 0.0.3
vscode-data-preview | Ran | 2.0.0
ruby | reb | 0.27.0
java | red | 0.66.0
code-settings-sync | Sha | 3.4.3
trailing-spaces | sha | 0.3.1
guides | spy | 0.9.3
addDocComments | ste | 0.0.8
vscodeintellicode | Vis | 1.2.10
vscode-java-debug | vsc | 0.28.0
vscode-java-dependency | vsc | 0.13.0
vscode-java-pack | vsc | 0.10.0
vscode-java-test | vsc | 0.24.1
vscode-maven | vsc | 0.24.2
vscode-icons | vsc | 10.2.0
vscode-wakatime | Wak | 4.0.7
jinja | who | 0.0.8
vscode-ruby | win | 0.27.0
JavaScriptSnippets | xab | 1.8.0
```

### Settings.json

```
{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "git.ignoreLegacyWarning": true,
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 50000,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
        "workbench.action.quickOpen"
    ],
    "editor.rulers": [
        80,
        120
    ],
    "dashboard.projectData": null,
    "java.requirements.JDK11Warning": false,
    "java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
}
```

Comment: You should first disable all extensions and see if it solves your problem. Also don't keep all extensions enabled when you don't need it. For example, in python project you don't want extensions related to Java or JavaScript. You should keep extensions globally enabled if you need it for all project, like extensions for git. The remaining extensions can be enabled for a specific workspace only.

Comment: @isAif Thanks for your comment but after uninstalling unused extensions, does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Ctrl+K+C` ?
and to uncomment use `Ctrl+K+U` .

And the issue with your vscode might be that the shortcut is not registered.
Follow this link to register the shortcut, if you prefer `Ctrl+/`.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.ToggleComment

Comment: For JAVA codes, both `Ctrl+K+C` and `Ctrl+/` works but for python codes, both do not work. I think there is some problem with python extension